# Blazor not recognizing added package

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've added the Mudblazor package to my Blazor Web Assembly project through nuget but for some reason intellisense doesn't recognize the file anywhere.

[Visual Studio Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht1Ri.png)

Comment: I think you might have a .Net core 3.2 project (based on System.net.Http.Json 3.2.0)
and Mudblazor for .net 5 (5.0.3 is dependant on .net 5) they have a version Mudblazor  2.0.3 which takes a dependancy on .netcore 3.1.12 which should work or upgrade your project to .net 5

Comment: @DavidMasterson is right. You have to target .net 5